# Sass, @media “767px is not a valid css value”

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, compass-sass

I can't run the project, because of this error.
[image]

Declaration :

```
$max767 : only screen and (max-width: 767px);
```

here is the code that is causing the problem :

```
@media #{$max767} {
  .fc-left,
  .fc-right,
  .fc-center {
    display: flex;
    float: none;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: $module-rem;
  }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare $max767 in string format `$max767: "(max-width : 767px)"`

Comment: prefix variable name with $ => $max767

Comment: It's already declared :
$max767 : only screen and (max-width: 767px);

Comment: You need to add quotation mark $max767: “only screen and (max-width: 767px)”;

Comment: The quote worked!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is just a little off. This works:

```
$max767: “only screen and (max-width: 767px)”;
@media #{$max767} {
    /* css here */
}
```